# How to use UISwitch to tell the controller to check a certain condition in a method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

In my card matching game:

-I have a method that checking cards that were flipped in certain index. It's basically the whole logic in the app.

-I have another method that checks the matching.

Now, I created a switch button in my view controller that will tell the controller that the user changed the mode for "3" cards instead of the basic mode (2 cards).

My issue is, how do i tell the controller to check in the matching method if there is more than 2 matches..it's driving me crazy please try to help me figure this out.

I also have in the controller an updateUI method that making cards that are matched fade away so I need to make sure it behaves the same.

The following code show's the flipCardAtIndex method, matching method & view controller in the same order:

CardMatchingGame.m (the last method is flipCardAtIndex):

```
#import "CardMatchingGame.h"
#import "PlayingCardsDeck.h"

@interface CardMatchingGame()

@property (readwrite, nonatomic) int score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cards;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *notification;
@end        


@implementation CardMatchingGame


-(NSMutableArray *) cards {

    if (!_cards) _cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _cards;
}


-(id)initWithCardCount:(NSUInteger)count usingDeck:(Deck *)deck {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Card *card = [deck drawRandonCard];

            if (!card) {
                self = nil;
            } else {
                self.cards[i] = card;
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(Card *) cardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    return (index < self.cards.count) ? self.cards[index] : nil;
}

#define FLIP_COST 1
#define MISMATCH_PENALTY 2
#define BONUS 4

-(void) flipCardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {



    Card *card = [self cardAtIndex:index];

    if (!card.isUnplayable) {

        if (!card.isFaceUp) {

            for (Card *otherCard in self.cards) {

                if (otherCard.isFaceUp && !otherCard.isUnplayable) {

                    NSMutableArray *myCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                    [myCards addObject:otherCard];

                    int matchScore = [card match:myCards];

                    if (matchScore) {

                        otherCard.unplayble = YES;
                        card.unplayble = YES;

                        self.notification = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ & %@  match!", card.contents, otherCard.contents];

                        self.score += matchScore * BONUS;
                    } else {
                        otherCard.faceUp = NO;
                        self.score -= MISMATCH_PENALTY;
                        self.notification = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ did not matched to %@", card.contents, otherCard.contents];
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
            self.score -= FLIP_COST;
        }
        card.faceUp = !card.isFaceUp;   
    }
}
@end
```

PlayingCards.m (Only the first method, matching method) :

```
#import "PlayingCards.h"


@implementation PlayingCards

@synthesize suit = _suit;

//overriding the :match method of cards to give different acore if its only a suit match or a number match
-(int)match:(NSArray *)cardToMatch {

    int score = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cardToMatch.count; i++) {

        PlayingCards *nextCard = cardToMatch[i];
        if ([nextCard.suit isEqualToString:self.suit]) {

            score += 1;
        } else if (nextCard.rank == self.rank) {

            score += 4;
        }
    }

   return score;

}
```

My view controller (the last method is the one for the switch button) :

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"
#import "PlayingCardsDeck.h"
#import "CardMatchingGame.h"


@interface CardGameViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipsLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *notificationLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreCounter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *game;
@property (nonatomic) int flipsCount;

@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *mode;
//@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;

@end


@implementation CardGameViewController

@synthesize mode = _mode;

//creating the getter method that creates a new card game.
-(CardMatchingGame *) game {

    if (!_game) _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:self.cardButtons.count usingDeck:[[PlayingCardsDeck alloc] init]];
    return _game;
}

//creating a setter for the IBOutletCollection cardButtons
-(void) setCardButtons:(NSArray *)cardButtons {

    _cardButtons = cardButtons;
   [self updateUI];
}


//creating the setter for the flipCount property. Whick is setting the flipsLabel to the right text and adding the number of counts.
-(void) setFlipsCount:(int)flipsCount {

    _flipsCount = flipsCount;
    self.flipsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d", self.flipsCount];

}


-(void) updateUI {

    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons) {
        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton]];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
        cardButton.selected = card.isFaceUp;
        cardButton.enabled = !card.unplayble;
        if (card.unplayble) {
            cardButton.alpha = 0.1;
        }

        //updating the score 
        self.scoreCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", self.game.score];

        //if notification in CardMatchingGame.m is no nil, it will be presented 
        if (self.game.notification) {

        self.notificationLabel.text = self.game.notification;

        }
    }
}

//Here I created a method to flipCards when the card is selected, and give the user a random card from the deck each time he flips the card. After each flip i'm incrementing the flipCount setter by one.
- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.game flipCardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender] forMode:self.mode];
    self.flipsCount++;
    [self updateUI];
}

//sending an alert if the user clicked on new game button
- (IBAction)newGame:(UIButton *)sender {

   UIAlertView* mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure..?" message:@"This will start a new game" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

    [mes show];

}

//preforming an action according to the user choice for the alert yes/no to start a new game
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {

        self.flipsCount = 0;
        self.game = nil;
        for (UIButton *button in self.cardButtons) {
            Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:button]];
            card.unplayble = NO;
            card.faceUp = NO;
            button.alpha = 1;
        }

        self.notificationLabel.text = nil;
        [self updateUI];

    }
}

-(void) setMode:(NSNumber *)mode {

    mode = _mode;
}

-(void) switchValueChange:(id)sender {

    UISwitch *Switch = (UISwitch *) sender;

    NSNumber *twoCards = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
    NSNumber *threeCards = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];


    if (Switch.on) {
        self.mode = twoCards;
    }
    else
    {
        self.mode = threeCards;
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UISwitch *mySwitch;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self updateUI];

}

@end
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what youre asking here. Are you just having trouble writing a method to compare three cards at once?

Comment: hey Max, no, im trying to see how do the model could recognize that he needs to test 3 cards instead of one , and pass that to the controller. (and of course the switch should tell the controller that he needs to ask this calculation from the model, very very new to mvc so i hope i got that right). the method that calculate matches already doing the job. the problem is how this method hands the controller matching of 3 instead of 2 @Max

Answer (score 0):

Actually, getting the switch value is the easy part. You can get set a referencing outlet from your switch to your viewController (CardGameViewController), and in your view controller's viewDidLoad method, add the method to listen for changes to switch's value:

```
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Add a new property called `NSNumber *mode` in your CardGameViewController and synthesize it. 
Now you can update the "mode" (which I believe could be an instance variable) in switchValueChanged method:

```
- (void)switchValueChange:(id)sender
  {
      UISwitch *switch = (UISwitch *) sender;
      if (sender.on)
        self.mode = 2;
      else
        self.mode = 3;
  }
```

If my assumption is right, then by "mode" you mean how many cards to match, is that correct? 2 means, that atleat 2 cards should be same when faced up, and 3 means, that 3 cards should match in suit or number.

Start by changing the match method in your PlayingCards to something like this (accepting another parameter named mode) (You might have to update the same method in its parent class too):

```
//overriding the :match method of cards to give different acore if its only a suit match or a number match
-(int)match:(NSArray *)cardToMatch forMode:(NSNumber *) mode{

    int score = 0;
    int cardsMatched = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cardToMatch.count; i++) {

        PlayingCards *nextCard = cardToMatch[i];
        if ([nextCard.suit isEqualToString:self.suit]) {

            score += 1;
            cardsMatched++;
        } else if (nextCard.rank == self.rank) {

            score += 4;
            cardsMatched++;
        }

        if (cardsMatched >= [mode intValue])
          break;

    }

   return score;

}
```

Now, in your CardMatchingGame.m method, change the flipCardAtIndex method to this (accepting another parameter named mode):

```
-(void) flipCardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index forMode (NSNumber *mode) {

    Card *card = [self cardAtIndex:index];

    if (!card.isUnplayable) {

        if (!card.isFaceUp) {

            NSMutableArray *myFaceUpCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



            // UPDATED: Loop through all the cards that are faced up and add them to an array first
            for (Card *otherCard in self.cards) {

                if (otherCard.isFaceUp && !otherCard.isUnplayable && orderCard != card) {

                    [myCards addObject:otherCard];
             }

             // UPDATED: Now call the method to do the match. The match method now takes an extra parameter
                    int matchScore = [card match:myCards forMode:mode];



                    if (matchScore) {

                        otherCard.unplayble = YES;
                        card.unplayble = YES;

                        self.notification = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ & %@  match!", card.contents, otherCard.contents];

                        self.score += matchScore * BONUS;
                    } else {
                        otherCard.faceUp = NO;
                        self.score -= MISMATCH_PENALTY;
                        self.notification = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ did not matched to %@", card.contents, otherCard.contents];
                    }

            }
            self.score -= FLIP_COST;
        }
        card.faceUp = !card.isFaceUp;   
    }
}
```

Finally, change call to

```
[self.game flipCardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender]];
```

in

```
- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender
```

method of CardGameViewController to

```
[self.game flipCardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender] forMode:self.mode];
```

Take a look and see if that makes sense.

Comment: where should I declare the `mode` property?

Comment: Whichever viewController has the UISwitch embedded. I have assumed here that it's CardMatchingGame.

Comment: the CardMatchingGame is the model, and the controller with the switch is the CardGameViewController (the last class i shared). I think I fixed the issue that I had, when I tried to use the new match: method i got an error that i'm missing a property `mode`, so I added a `property (nonatomic) int mode` to the CardMatchingGame (where the flipCards logic at). is that ok?

Comment: i couldn't test it since i'm trying to figure out the controller now :?

Comment: the PlayingCards class has the match: method , the CardMatchingGame has the logic of the flipping cards (both of them part of the model) , and the CardGameViewController is my controller. i'm really stuck with this it's driving me crazy @AC1

Comment: only getting error on this line `[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` @AC1

Comment: i you meant i should create `property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;` right? i tried that too..@AC1

Comment: im getting 2 errors on this line: `[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` 1 is "unknown reciver" and the second "un known class method for selector 'addTarget:actionforControlEvent' " @AC1

Comment: if i create `UISwitch *mySwitch;` before, it works, but the algorithm is not behaving well..

Comment: Yes, you need to create an outlet for your UISwitch from your storyboard, which I think you already did. Are you still getting errors? And how's the algorithm not behaving properly? Did you try to debug using breakpoints if all the functions are getting invoked correctly and the mode is getting set to the right value or not?

Comment: I'v updated the controller to my question, see how it looks now please. I'm not getting errors now, but if I choose a card i cant flip it back, and also when i find him a match it also makes bunch of other cards unplayable...i'm trying to debug it, but i'm new in iOS programming (and in programming in general actually) so it's not that quick for me :? @AC1

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;` from your .m class. 
Instead, go to your storyboard, click on the controller that has the switch, then click on the Assistant Editor button on top right (looks like a face). It will open up CardGameViewController.h. Now right click on the switch view on the storyoard, and click and drag from New Referencing Outlet to CardViewController.h. This is how you reference your switch into your controller.
Now that you have the switch variable in the interface file, go to your implementation file (CardGameViewController.m) and synthesize the variable:

```
@synthesize mySwitch = _mySwitch;
```

Now, change your viewDidLoad method to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self updateUI];

}
```

Also remove setMode method. If you are synthesizing mode variable, then you don't need it.

Give it a try now. You know how to debug in xcode using breakpoints?